# Given a function $x^a y^{1-a}$, confusion about how the curves vary as I very $\alpha$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have the function $$F(x,y) = x^a y^{1-a} = 1$$ where $a \in [0,1]$.

$$g(x,y) = - \frac{\partial F /\partial x}{\partial F / \partial y} = \frac{a}{1-a} \frac{y}{x} $$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} = -\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}\frac{y}{x}$$

So suppose I have the following set of graphs: 
[image]

Here I just picked some values. Red is $a = \frac{1}{4}$, blue is $a = \frac{1}{2}$, black is $a = \frac{3}{4}$

I understand how the steepness and flatness of the different curves change as I vary $a$. But I am confused as to what $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} $ tells me about the graph. In particular, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} $ is dependent on $a$. So even though I know $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$ tells me how much $g$ changes as I change $a$....changing $a$ changes $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$...so I am very confused!

**My Question**

What is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$ telling me about the graph? Since $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$ is dependent on $a$, how does this affect things?

Comment: When you look at the function $f(x)=x^2$, $f'(x)=2x$ depends on $x$.  Is that something that seems reasonable?  If so, the situation you have is not different in kind from the simple parabolic equation, is it?

Comment: You are right. I myself actually thought of that very example. But it didn't help me. I couldn't use that intuition to answer my question even though I know that is the basic idea.

Comment: So, you're OK then?

Comment: No, I still don't get it. Oh wait, if I have $f(x) = x^2$ and I choose the point $x=2$ I get $f(2) = 4$. But if I take $f'(x)$, this gives me the slope at this point of a tangent line. So the $x$ varying isn't really relevant in the sense that...at whatever point I choose, the slope is then still $2x$

Comment: Okay, so then that resolves the question of how $a$ affects $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$. But I still don't get what $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$ tells me about the graph. Maybe part of my confusion is.....for the $x^2$ and $2x$ example, I can imagine $f(x)$ and also $f'(x)$ at the point of tangency, but I can't seem to visualize what is going on in the graph above.